# Does python have a call_user_func() like PHP?

Tags: php, python

Does python have a function like `call_user_func()` in PHP?

PHP Version:

```
call_user_func(array($object,$methodName),$parameters)
```

How do I achieve the above in Python?

Comment: You can simply call it like this: obj.method_name(parameters). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Let's there are two classes-

class Spam(object):
   ...
class Egg(object):
  ...
And I have a variable:
cls_name #will be either Spam or Egg

I want to be able to call the __init__() method of the class whose name is stored in cls_name method.

Hope I have made it clear.

Comment: Why would you call the initializer for a class that's already initialized?  In any case, that's a very different question. Please modify your question to suit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking which object to instantiate isn't that hard.  A class is a first-class object and can be assigned to a variable or passed as an argument to a function.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__( self, arg1, arg2 ):
         etc.

class B(object):
    def __init__( self, arg1, arg2 ):
         etc.

thing_to_make = A
argList= ( some, pair )
thing_to_make( *argList )

thing_to_make = B
argList- ( another, pair )
thing_to_make( *argList )

def doSomething( class_, arg1, arg2 ):
    thing= class_( arg1, arg2 )
    thing.method()
    print thing
```

All works nicely without much pain.  You don't need a "call_user_function" sort of thing in Python

Comment: like this idea. would have given you vote if stack overflow allowed me to. thanks

Answer (score 9):

I don't see the problem, unless `methodName` is a string. In that case [getattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) does the job:

```
>>> class A:
...     def func(self, a, b):
...         return a + b
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> getattr(a, 'func')(2, 3)
5
```

If `object` is also a string, then this would work, using [globals](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals) or [locals](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) (but then you may have other, bigger, problems):

```
>>> getattr(locals()['a'], 'func')(2, 3)
5
>>> getattr(globals()['a'], 'func')(2, 3)
5
```

---

**Edit**: re your clarification. To initialise an object based on a string:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self): print('a')
... 
>>> class B:
...     def __init__(self): print('b')
... 
>>> clsStr = 'A'
>>> myObj = locals()[clsStr]()
a
```

I am not sure if this is really what you want though... unless you have many different classes, why not just perform string matching?

---

**Another edit**: Though the above works, you should seriously consider going with a solution such as provided by [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856992/does-python-have-a-calluserfunc-like-php/857294#857294). For one thing, by storing all possible classes in a `dict`, you avoid strange behaviour that may result from passing an incorrect string argument which just happens to match the name of a non-related class in the current scope.

Comment: eval is evil. Better use globals() or locals() instead.

Comment: muhuk: How would you *instantiate* a new object from its class, given a sample object?

Comment: @muhuk: You're right. I decided to remove eval() from my answer (those interested can still have a look at the change history).

Comment: @Arafangion: I asked myself the same question, but as you can see in my edited answer, it is in fact possible :)

Comment: What if 'A' indicates a class that is not in either the local or global namespace?

Comment: Stephan202: Indeed, I've learnt something new - though I'm still dubious it's the whole answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to use classes from far-off places (and in fact, if you need any classes at all) then you're best off creating and using a dictionary for them:

```
funcs = {'Eggs': foo.Eggs, 'Spam': bar.Spam}

def call_func(func_name, *args, **kwargs):
    if not func_name in funcs:
        raise ValueError('Function %r not available' % (func_name,))
    return funcs[func_name](*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Under most circumstances this solution is to be preferred over the (albeit more general) locals()/globals() trick.

Comment: ...which is why I now referenced this answer in my answer, with an additional argument for its use.

Answer (score 1):

For a given object 'obj', a given method name 'meth', and a given set of arguments 'args':

```
    obj.__getattribute__(meth)(*args)
```

Should get you there.

Of course, it goes without saying - What the heck is it you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can call use getattr with locals() or globals() to do something similar

```
# foo.method() is called if it's available in global scope
getattr(globals()['foo'], 'method')(*args)

# Same thing, but for 'foo' in local scope
getattr(locals()['foo'], 'method')(*args)
```

See also: **Dive Into Python** on [getattr()](http://www.diveintopython.org/power_of_introspection/getattr.html), on [locals() and globals()](http://www.diveintopython.org/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html)

Comment: Didn't answer the question - unless $object is the global namespace.

Comment: (the edited version) Does the same thing. $object has to exist somewhere for the PHP example (either in function or global scope)

Comment: I'd remove my negative vote if stack overflow allowed me, as it now looks good. (Apparently it's too old).